# Power Query - Conditional Max Statement

Tags: max, powerquery

I am trying to write a custom formula to get the max date(Column 4) for each Item Number(Column 1) and Movement Type(Column 7) in it's own column.  I realize I could Group By Item Number and Movement Type to get the result, but would like to see the result as a separate column in the full data set. [

The following applied step would get the result.  Is there a way to do this with a conditional max statement?

`= Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Item Number", "Movement Type  Name"}, {{"Max Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}})`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwr5M.png)

Comment: Include an aggregation of `All Rows` as well as the Max.  Then expand that column with the Table.

Comment: Any sense of which works faster on your data set?  This Group/expand or the custom column answer you accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would add the max Date, grouped by Item Number and Movement Type, without grouping.  Likely grouping then expanding is faster

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1","Max Date",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns1", each [Item Number]=i[Item Number] and [Movement Type]=i[Movement Type]) [Date]), type date ),
```